# QGIS 3.12 print composer - how to rotate map but keep grid unrotated?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, vector-grid

I am creating a map using QGIS 3.12 and wish to rotate the map and add a grid using print composer, but I want to keep the grid unrotated.

Is this possible or does the grid only rotate with the map?

Comment: that makes no sense - the grid is intimately related to the map's orientation

Comment: @IanTurton it is common to have a non-geographic grid to locate items (ex: letter A-E for columns, 1-10 for rows, then an index says "feature ABC: B-4")

Comment: I wish to retain the geographic grid, but I want to display it unrotated - it is projected so I don't think it necessarily relates to the map's orientation?

Comment: @JGH not sure I'd agree *common* but ok then cm will work

Answer (score 1):

If you use an interval in `cm` instead of `map unit`, then the grid will not be rotated
[image]

Comment: do you need to set a specific EPSG for the grid or does this work for all CRS ?

Comment: @JGH thanks but I want to retain the geographical distance for the grid, I don't think this solution does?

Comment: @Chris if you have a fixed scale you may calculate how many centimetre relate to the geographical distance you want to use for your grid and set that in the X and Y distance it's a bit of manual setting but better than nothing

Comment: @JGH yes that might be the only way, thanks for the idea.

Comment: else you would have to create a vector layer grid, with the opposite rotation

Comment: I am creating multiple maps per page so don't think that will be an option - I have found this site https://rechneronline.de/scale/ that allows for calculating distances which seems to provide a solution using the grid values as above.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another unrotated map on top of your rotated map, that follows a theme which shows no layers, and create the grid with the given scale in this dummy map.